Benders Cut Concerning Objective
I am trying to generate a linear lower bound approximation for a subproblem of Benders Decomposition:
$$
\begin{align}
V(z_1,z_2) = \min_{y} \quad &   (q-z_1)^\top y \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & Tz_2 + Gy \leq h \\
& y \geq 0
\end{align}
$$
where $(z_1\geq0,z_2\geq0)$ are fixed and from the Master Problem, $y$ is the 2nd stage decision variable, $q,T,G,h$ are considered as constants. If I apply the standard Benders Decomposition:
$$
\begin{align}
\max_{\lambda\geq0} \quad & \lambda^\top(Tz_2 - h) \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & q-z_1 + G^\top \lambda \geq 0 \\
\end{align}
$$
If we take the optimal dual variable $\lambda^*(z_1,z_2)$ for possible coming new solution $(z_3,z_4)$, it may be problematic to use it again since $z_3$ could change the feasible region of the dual problem.
Therefore, could you please give me any ideas regarding the construction of the linear lower bound, or some related papers with similar structure?

Hello. Could you elaborate more? For instance, could you take some time to, first, describe the corresponding Master Problem, and then, sequentially present the subproblem along with its dual? Also, maybe present what you have done so far? Thanks and regards.
